# Зачем чекбоксам разные значения атрибута name?

Tags: html

Говорят, что для правильной работы чекбокса нужно ставить каждому разное значение атрибута name. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, зачем?

Пример:

```
<div>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="color-green" value="green">Green</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="color-red" value="red">Red</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="color-blue" value="blue">Blue</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Чекбоксы с разными именами не будут обрабатываться вместе. С одним именем - будут.

Comment: @Quazimorda что такое "обрабатываться вместе"?

Comment: @andreymal если чекбоксы имеют одно имя, они связаны, значения их можно обрабатывать вместе, как единый массив значений. https://runebook.dev/ru/docs/html/element/input/checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Они не обязательны, если ты не хочешь получить результат,- доступ к чекбоксу осуществляется по его имени.

Comment: Ответ не совсем понятен, как в случае с "казнить нельзя помиловать", уточните формулировку.

Answer (score 0):

Name - имя должно говорить само за себя.
Условно у вас родились дети и вы их назвали одним именем, при обращении к ним как они поймут к кому Вы обратились?
Тут тоже самое, когда ваш условный код (php или js) обращается к данным чекбокса, с одинаковыми именами он не поймет, откуда ему нужно брать данные.
Если Вас это не устраивает, Вы можете написать собственный код обработки через js используя собственный одноименный атрибут и с собрать все в массив.

Comment: PHP сам прекрасно умеет собирать массив https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: @andreymal, извиняюсь, не упомянул о php, ответ был написал исходя из своих предпочтений.